# Add 0 before minutes 1-9

Tags: jquery, date, time

I am getting the current time via jQuery and then doing some clever bits to show/hide a shop open sign based on the time.

My current code works well, apart from when the time is 0-9 minutes past the hour in which case it fails and incorrectly shows the CLOSED statement. The reason being that the time is being rendered as 119 for example 11:09 - what I need it is written as 1109 rather than 119.

Code is:

```
 tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

 function GetClock(){
 var d=new Date();
 var jwdday=d.getDay(),ap;
 var jwdtime = d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes(),gp;

 /* sign logic */
 if (jwdday != "0") {
   if((jwdtime < 1800 && jwdtime >= 1400) || (jwdtime < 1300 && jwdtime >= 700)) {
 document.getElementById('signStatus').innerHTML="<img src='http://www.hawkesbury-stores.co.uk/wp-content/themes/HawkSOS/images/core/weareOpen.png' alt='We are currently OPEN' title='We are currently OPEN' class='weareOpen'>";
   }
   else {
     document.getElementById('signStatus').innerHTML="<img src='weareClosed.png' alt='We are currently CLOSED' title='We are currently CLOSED' class='weareClosed'>";
   }
 }
 else if(jwdtime < 1230 && jwdtime >= 700){
 document.getElementById('signStatus').innerHTML="<img src='weareOpen.png' alt='We are currently OPEN' title='We are currently OPEN' class='weareOpen'>";
 }
 else {
 document.getElementById('signStatus').innerHTML="<img src='weareClosed.png' alt='We are currently CLOSED' title='We are currently CLOSED' class='weareClosed'>";
 }


 }

 window.onload=function(){
 GetClock();
 setInterval(GetClock,1000);
 }
```

Comment: `var min = minutes > 10 ? minutes  : "0" + minutes ;` something like this

Comment: Thanks - yes, that approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the hours and minutes arithmetically (comparing them to numbers), so you can do something like

`var jwdtime = 100*d.getHours() + d.getMinutes();`